# Почему в данном коде берется последний элемент списка,если он не подходит под условие

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lst = ['aaabb', 'caca', 'dabc', 'acc', 'abbb']
res = ','.join(i for i in lst if i.find('c')!=-1)
print(res)
```

Comment: у меня не берется в IDLE - `caca,dabc,acc` на выходе.

Comment: У меня тоже не берётся.

Comment: Не совсем понял проблему, но попробуйте: `[i for i in lst if 'c' in i]`

Comment: Можете описать, где именно у Вас берётся этот последний элемент, в каком интерпретаторе, среде разработки и проч.?

Answer (score -1):

**Никита**, ваша программа работает верно и последний элемент **не** берётся

```
lst = [ 'aaabb', 'caca', 'dabc', 'acc', 'abbb' ]
res = ','.join( i for i in lst if i.find('c') != -1 )
print( res )

'''
Кондратьев Никита
'''
```

Результат работы программы:

```
caca,dabc,acc
```

Что является правильным ответом, потому что в коде прописано брать все элементы, в которых присутствует символ ц ( `c` )